# Is it safe to frequently open & close hdf5 files?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

My data pipeline is frequently interrupted, resulting in unclosed hdf5-files; read access is required about once per second. Instead of keeping the file open and reading from it directly, I'm considering `with ...: data = hdf5[key]` to guarantee closure. I've read that concurrent access to an hdf5 file may corrupt it, but haven't found material on frequent opens & closures; is there any stability / corruption concern to note?

*Note*: I access a small fraction (1/100) of the data (60GB+) at a time, iteratively, different chunk each time, and in a loop (different access order each time).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think for hdf5 it's possible that you have to load a full structure to alter it, like loading a giant JSON? In which case, I/O could take quite a bit of time. Or, maybe I was using it wrong when I played with it a while back :)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It's a sanity check - hdf5 is a complex data structure, anything goes. Why would it, for example, not allow deleting arrays from itself, or have various intermittent [corruption problems](https://cyrille.rossant.net/moving-away-hdf5/)? Who knows - hence the question.

Comment: I always use the `with h5py.File() as h5f:` construct for production code to ensure closure. I don't do concurrent read access, so can't comment on that. You should be fine you open in "read" mode. Look at SWMR mode (Single Write, Multiple Read) if you need read access from several concurrent processes. Also, you do not need to open/close the file to access the data. Open once, then access as you need and close at the end.